# SignalR failing to work

Tags: jquery, html, signalr

I am getting started with SignalR so I am following this old build event : https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-034. I have followed the demo step by step by on my machine it's not working. I am using VS 2015 Community Edition with Update 3, jquery-1.12.4, jquery-ui.1.12.1 and jquery.signalR-2.2.1. I created an empty website and added the following components

MoveShapeHub.cs: (it's on the root)

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace Study.SignalR
{
    [HubName("moveShape")]
    public class MoveShapeHub : Hub
    {
        public void MoveShape(int x, int y)
        {
            Clients.Others.shapeMoved(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

moveShape.js (it's in a folder named MoveShape)

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js" />

$(function () {

    var hub = $.connection.moveShape;
    $shape = $("#shape");
    hub.client.shapeMoved = function (x, y) {
        $shape.css({ left: x, top: y });
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $shape.draggable({
            drag: function () {
                hub.server.moveShape(this.offsetLeft, this.offsetTop || 0)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

index.html (it's in a folder named MoveShape)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        #shape{
            width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#b200ff; cursor: move;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="shape">

    </div>

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="MoveShape/moveShape.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean saying "failing to work"? where does error occur?

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `<script src="moveShape.js"></script>`? Because index.html and moveShape.js are in the same folder. Use tools in the browser (F12) to get more details about what is failing or whether everything is loaded correctly and the code is actually being executed (you can set a breakpoint)